# The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'. (argument_type_not_assignable)

Tags: flutter, dart

I've got two issues here:
number one is for id:null,
The argument type 'Null' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dart

number two is title: value,
The argument type 'String?' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'String'.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_shop/providers/product.dart';

class EditProductScreen extends StatefulWidget {
static const routeName = '/edit-product';

@override
State<EditProductScreen> createState() => _EditProductScreenState();
}

class _EditProductScreenState extends State<EditProductScreen> {
final _priceFocusNode = FocusNode();
final _descriptionFocusNode = FocusNode();
final _imageUrlFocusNode = FocusNode();
final _imageUrlController = TextEditingController();
final _form = GlobalKey<FormState>();
var _editedProduct =
  Product(id: null, title: '', description: '', price: 0.0, imageUrl: '');

  @override
  void initState() {
  _imageUrlFocusNode.addListener(_updateImageUrl);
  super.initState();
  }

@override
void dispose() {
_imageUrlFocusNode.removeListener(_updateImageUrl);
_priceFocusNode.dispose();
_descriptionFocusNode.dispose();
_imageUrlFocusNode.dispose();
_imageUrlController.dispose();
super.dispose();
}

void _updateImageUrl() {
  if (_imageUrlFocusNode.hasFocus) {
    setState(() {});
   }
  }

void _saveForm() {
 _form.currentState!.save();
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: const Text('edit product'),
    actions: <Widget>[
      IconButton(
        onPressed: _saveForm,
        icon: const Icon(Icons.save),
      )
    ],
  ),
  body: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
    child: Form(
        key: _form,
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Title'),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_priceFocusNode);
              },
              onSaved: (value) {
                _editedProduct = Product(
                    id: null,
                    title: value,
                    description: _editedProduct.description,
                    price: _editedProduct.price,
                    imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl);
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Price'),
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
              focusNode: _priceFocusNode,
              onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_descriptionFocusNode);
              },
              onSaved: (value) {
                _editedProduct = Product(
                    id: null,
                    title: _editedProduct.title,
                    description: _editedProduct.description,
                    price:double.parse(value),
                    imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl);
              },
            ),
            TextFormField(
              decoration: const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Description'),
              maxLines: 3,
              textInputAction: TextInputAction.next,
              keyboardType: TextInputType.multiline,
              focusNode: _descriptionFocusNode,
              onSaved: (value) {
                _editedProduct = Product(
                    id: null,
                    title: _editedProduct.title,
                    description: value,
                    price: _editedProduct.price,
                    imageUrl: _editedProduct.imageUrl);
              },
            ),
            Row(
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                    width: 100,
                    height: 100,
                    margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 8, right: 10),
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(width: 1, color: Colors.grey)),
                    child: _imageUrlController.text.isEmpty
                        ? const Text('Enter a URL!')
                        : FittedBox(
                            child: Image.network(_imageUrlController.text),
                            fit: BoxFit.cover,
                          )),
                Expanded(
                  child: TextFormField(
                    decoration:
                        const InputDecoration(labelText: 'Image URL'),
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.url,
                    textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                    controller: _imageUrlController,
                    focusNode: _imageUrlFocusNode,
                    onSaved: (value) {
                      _editedProduct = Product(
                          id: null,
                          title: _editedProduct.title,
                          description: _editedProduct.description,
                          price: _editedProduct.price,
                          imageUrl: value);
                    },
                    onFieldSubmitted: (_) {
                      _saveForm();
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            )
          ],
        )),
  ),
);
}
}
```

Please help me out and resolve these issues.
here are the screenshots:
[image]

[image]

Comment: Modify your `Product()` class to accept nullable value by adding a question mark in the variable type. `Product({final String? id, final String? title})`

Comment: You can't assign `null` to a `String`, it would need to be a `String?` then. I haven't thoroughly checked your code but maybe just changing `final String id;` to `final String? id;` solves it

Comment: I can't edit my Product class to String? because therefore there will be more errors in other files and codes I have. Here inside the codes, I have to do something.

Comment: then maybe assign empty string instead of `null` to the id. It simply is impossible to be `null` like that

Comment: what can I do with value which is String? but my title, description, ... are String.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you need to learn what the null safety is. If you create some variables with ?, that is nullable variable, so that variable can receive null. For example, if you create variable like this: String? id. It can receive null value.

You might use the example below:

```
class Product{
String? id
String? title
}
Product({required this.id, required this.title});
```

Secondly, if you are giving value to your variable that is not nullable, you can use ?? and give default value in case the value is null. For example,
_editedProduct = Product(
id:null,
title: value??""
)